# Chunk File Upload using BlueImp Jquery File Upload

Tags: jquery, file-upload, blueimp

I try to implement chunk file upload using `BlueImp` **[Jquery File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)** 
in my project and everything work fine 
until i try to implement alternative file name in it
im using code provide in BlueImp Wiki :

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
  maxChunkSize: 1000000,
  add: function(e, data) {
    var count = data.files.length;
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      data.files[i].uploadName =
        Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + '_' + data.files[i].name;
    }
    data.submit();
  }
});
```

The code above only work when the file size not bigger than `maxfileChunk`